# opencv cv::solve() gives a wrong answers

Tags: c++, opencv

when I use opencv `cv::solve()` to solve a least-squares problems like get the x in Ax=b,I use like this:

```
cv::solve(A, B, coeff,cv::DECOMP_LU);
```

In my test example, `A` is a 6x6 `mat`, `B` is a 6x1 `mat`, `coeff` is the output 6x1 `mat`.
All of the type is CV_64FC1 .
When I use MATLAB func x = lscov(A,B) to solve it , the answer is different with the answer in opencv used `cv::solve()`. I don't know why and how to fix it.

This is my `A` mat:

```
       13650        2646        8281        1911        9261         546
        2646         546        1911         441        1911         126
        8281        1911       13650        2646        9261         546
        1911         441        2646         546        1911         126
        9261        1911        9261        1911        8281         441
         546         126         546         126         441          36
```

And this is my `B` mat

```
       10836
        2436
       14511
        2961
       10731
         666
```

When I use MATLAB I use like this

```
coeff = lscov(A,B);
```

The answer it gives is:

```
coeff =

    0.0000
    1.0000
   -0.0000
    6.0000
    0.0000
   -6.0000
```

When I use opencv `cv::solve()`, the answer it gives is:

```
[6.66296484815332e-17;
 -3.724946654716256;
 0.01073461162921725;
 0.0749237651372591;
 1.349984758490359;
 14.57495854564313]
```

It's strange and I don't know Why.
Please tell me how to get the right answer.

Comment: Show how mat `A` is filled out with data in your code.

Comment: @rafix07 I used a complex function to generate this matrix and occured some fault in the process. Thank u to tell me that, it's totally my problem, YOU ARE THE REAL HERO.Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `cv::solve` is totally same with the **matlab** function `lscov`. I just believe that your implementation is wrong. You can find my implemented code below. When I tried the inputs with `cv::solve` function I got the coefficient output:

```
[-3.831204787688159e-15;
 1.000000000000029;
 4.557012826684974e-15;
 5.99999999999997;
 -9.7745995234962e-16;
 -5.999999999999993]
```

which can be rounded to:

```
    0.0000
    1.0000
   -0.0000
    6.0000
    0.0000
   -6.0000
```

## Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>


int main()
{
    double xx[6][6] = {{13650, 2646, 8281, 1911, 9261, 546},
                       {2646, 546, 1911, 441, 1911, 126},
                       {8281, 1911, 13650, 2646, 9261, 546},
                       {1911, 441, 2646, 546, 1911, 126},
                       {9261, 1911, 9261, 1911, 8281, 441},
                       {546, 126, 546, 126, 441, 36}};

    double yy[1][6] = {{10836,2436,14511,2961,10731,666}};





    cv::Mat img(cv::Size(6,6),CV_64F,xx);
    cv::Mat img2(cv::Size(1,6),CV_64F,yy);

    cv::Mat coeff;
    cv::solve(img,img2,coeff,cv::DECOMP_CHOLESKY);

    std::cout<<img<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<img2<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<coeff<<std::endl;





}
```

**Note:** You can also find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maPxqJWuwiI&t=416s) my least square implemetation with the core algorithm I developed.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's my problem. You are very kind, I love you.